# Clone Magento 2 Installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm attempting to clone a Magento 2 barebones install, simply by compressing the site, exporting the db, extracting to another location, editing env.php for new db credentials, dumped old DB into new DB. All attempts to reach the install yield a 403 forbidden page.

I could force a reinstall, but it would kill all my extensions I've loaded.  There are no products/orders, I've just setup the base install I need for many sites.

Has anyone cloned Mage 2 successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the site load at all? Typically the problem is all the pre-generated/cached values in Magento 2, so to transfer your process might look like this -

1. Tarball/archive everything up including the DB
2. Move to the new server/web root you are using and extract
3. Clear ALL caches, pub/static included and the Magento cache and compiled files in var/
4. Update the base URLs and reindex if needed.
5. Re-deploy static files/dev mode (or production mode if you are using that)

All of the above should work, but the 403 sounds more like a webserver config issue/permissions, so I would start there first.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much I did all that and deployed static view files helped. Site is now visible, but I couldn't access the admin as its still hardcoded to the old admin.

I found web/unsecure/base_url in the DB and updated the entry and now the admin is available.

My first 2.0 install is here example.com/

my second 2.0 install is here example.com/abc/

Everything seems to work except for one thing...when I try to go to Web Setup Wizard...I get an odd url:  example.com/abc/setup

It stripped all the encryption key info out of the url and its basically a blank page.  I say basically because there is a tiny bit of styling but no content whatsoever.

Everything else in the admin is golden.  So weird.  Its the one page I need into right now!

Comment: Try moving the subdirectory install up, with Magento 1.x there are sometimes issues depending on the webserver configuration so they could be interfering with each other.  EDIT: By up I mean out the same webroot as the other install.